# Why doesn't appear second user control in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I designed user control for my project. I added this user control in page twice. I can see first user control in page but can't see second user control. Why?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "?Contents=1" at the end of page URL. and verify if second control exists or is closed.